# No module named 'torch'

Tags: python, pytorch

Когда пытаюсь импортировать pytorch в jupiterlab получаю ошибку

```
----> 2 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Перепроверил в командной строке, точно ли я скачал библиотеку. На изображении видно, что да, но тем не менее, ошибка есть[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо понять какой интерпритатор использует jupiterlab. Попробуйте выполнить из jupiterlab такие строчки `import sys` и `print(sys.executable)`. Это должно вывести путь до вашего интерпритатора.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров хорошо, а если используется не тот который нужен, как поменять

Comment: @mmmmmm вы используете anaconda-navigator?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров не заметил правку, нет

Comment: как вы устанавливали jupiterlab? через pip?

Comment: Если ставили через anaconda
| conda install -c anaconda mkl |

conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров да

Comment: Что выдает команда `pip freeze`? Есть ли там и ноутбук и торч?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров торч есть, а касательно ноутбука jupyter-client==7.0.2
jupyter-core==4.7.1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2. Возник вопрос, влияет ли место, откуда юпитер был запущен? Я запустил с диска C, там где то на нем есть версии питона которые мне не нужны, а необходимую я установил на D, и оттуда скачивал библиотеки

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров проверил, ему без разницы откуда. Удалил ненужные версии питона, перестал распознавать команды

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ввести команду:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

А затем снова попробовать установить модуль.
На всякий случай дам вам [ссылку: no-module-named-torch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843067/no-module-named-torch).